# prestashop 1.7 front office wrong redirection

Tags: apache2, prestashop-1.7

**Environment**

1. Prestashop 1.7.4.2
2. Ubuntu 16.04
3. Apache 2
4. Let's Encrypt

**Issue**

My prestashop installation is automatically getting redirected to https//domain.com

please note, there is no **:** after https, which is causing error in prestashop front office. I tried to add **:** manually in browser, but it still going to https//domain.com.

Where as, when I add **:** manually in browser for back office, it works.

I've also set `shop domain` and `ssl domain` as https://www.tureds.com

I'm really stuck here. Any help will be highly appreciated.

You can see the issue in action by visiting [tureds.com](http://tureds.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. After trying different combinations of options, I'm able to solve the issue, by following below steps.

1. disabled force redirection to https using apache
2. set `shop domain` and `ssl domain` as www.tureds.com -- *No https://*
3. goto configure -> shop parameters - > General
4. select *Yes* for `Enable SSL` and `Enable SSL on all pages` options

Mentioned issue will be resolved. This will also help to get rid of infinite url redirecting issue.